# How to use tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory() in the model.fit()?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Because I need train my model on the ImageNet with 1024 batchsize, I must use more than 2 GPUs, so I use the tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy() to trian, this Strategy can only use fit() not fit_generator(). However the ImageNet has large amount of data, I use the tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory() to Process data，but it makes some mistakes, my code is below:(I omitted some unimportant functions)

```
import os, sys, argparse
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from multi_gpu import ParallelModel

import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD, RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau, LearningRateScheduler, TerminateOnNaN
import tensorflow as tf

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1"

num_epochs = 5
batch_size_per_replica = 256
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print('Number of devices: %d' % strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)  # 输出设备数量
batch_size_all = batch_size_per_replica * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync

def preprocess(x):
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x /= 255.0
    x -= 0.5
    x *= 2.0
    return x

def main(args):
    log_dir = args.log_dir#'logs/'
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(args.model_save_dir + 'ep{epoch:03d}-val_loss{val_loss:.3f}-val_acc{val_acc:.3f}-val_top_k_categorical_accuracy{val_top_k_categorical_accuracy:.3f}.h5',
        monitor='val_acc',
        mode='max',
        verbose=1,
        save_weights_only=False,
        save_best_only=True,
        period=1)
    logging = TensorBoard(log_dir=args.model_save_dir, histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False, write_grads=False, write_images=False, update_freq='batch')
    terminate_on_nan = TerminateOnNaN()
    learn_rates = [0.05, 0.01, 0.005, 0.001, 0.0005, 0.0001]
    lr_scheduler = LearningRateScheduler(lambda epoch: learn_rates[epoch // 30])


    def make_train_generator():
        train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess,
                                       zoom_range=0.25,
                                       #shear_range=0.2,
                                       #channel_shift_range=0.1,
                                       #rotation_range=0.1,
                                       width_shift_range=0.05,
                                       height_shift_range=0.05,
                                       horizontal_flip=True)
        train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            args.train_data_path,
            target_size=(224, 224),
            batch_size=args.batch_size)
        total_train_samples = train_generator.samples
        return train_generator
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(make_train_generator, output_types=tf.float32, output_shapes=tf.TensorShape([224,224]))

    def make_test_generator():
        test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess) 
        test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            args.val_data_path,
            target_size=(224, 224),
            batch_size=args.batch_size)
        total_test_samples = test_generator.samples
        return test_generator
    test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(make_test_generator, output_types=tf.float32, output_shapes=tf.TensorShape([224,224]))

    optimizer = get_optimizer(args.optim_type, args.learning_rate)

    with strategy.scope():
    # prepare model
        model = get_model(args.model_type)   
        model.compile(
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy', 'top_k_categorical_accuracy'],
              loss='categorical_crossentropy')
        model.summary()
        print('Train on {} samples, val on {} samples, with batch size {}.'.format(train_generator.samples, test_generator.samples, args.batch_size))
    model.fit(
            train_dataset,
            batch_size=None,
            epochs=args.total_epoch,
            initial_epoch=args.init_epoch,
            validation_data=test_dataset,
            callbacks=[logging, checkpoint, lr_scheduler, terminate_on_nan])

    # Finally store model
    model.save(log_dir + 'trained_final.h5')
```

but this give me a strange mistake：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1352, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1337, in _run_fn
target_list, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1430, in _call_tf_sessionrun
run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
(0) Invalid argument: Cannot use rebatching fallback when 0th dimensions of dataset components are not fully known. Component 0 has shape: dim { size: -1 } dim { size: -1 } dim { size: -1 } dim { size: -1 }
[[{{node ExperimentalRebatchDataset_2_1}}]]
[[MultiDeviceIteratorInit_1/_4593]]
(1) Invalid argument: Cannot use rebatching fallback when 0th dimensions of dataset components are not fully known. Component 0 has shape: dim { size: -1 } dim { size: -1 } dim { size: -1 } dim { size: -1 }
[[{{node ExperimentalRebatchDataset_2_1}}]]
0 successful operations.
1 derived errors ignored.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "yolo3/models/backbones/imagenet_training/train_imagenet.py", line 242, in
main(args)
File "yolo3/models/backbones/imagenet_training/train_imagenet.py", line 200, in main
callbacks=[logging, checkpoint, lr_scheduler, terminate_on_nan])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 711, in fit
use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py", line 681, in fit
steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 203, in model_iteration
val_iterator = _get_iterator(val_inputs, model._distribution_strategy)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 546, in _get_iterator
inputs, distribution_strategy)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/distribute/distributed_training_utils.py", line 546, in get_iterator
initialize_iterator(iterator, distribution_strategy)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/distribute/distributed_training_utils.py", line 554, in initialize_iterator
K.get_session((init_op,)).run(init_op)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 945, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1168, in _run
feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1346, in _do_run
run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1371, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
(0) Invalid argument: Cannot use rebatching fallback when 0th dimensions of dataset components are not fully known. Component 0 has shape: dim { size: -1 } dim { size: -1 } dim { size: -1 } dim { size: -1 }
[[node ExperimentalRebatchDataset_2_1 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1657) ]]
[[MultiDeviceIteratorInit_1/_4593]]
(1) Invalid argument: Cannot use rebatching fallback when 0th dimensions of dataset components are not fully known. Component 0 has shape: dim { size: -1 } dim { size: -1 } dim { size: -1 } dim { size: -1 }
[[node ExperimentalRebatchDataset_2_1 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1657) ]]
0 successful operations.
1 derived errors ignored.
Original stack trace for 'ExperimentalRebatchDataset_2_1':
File "yolo3/models/backbones/imagenet_training/train_imagenet.py", line 242, in
main(args)
File "yolo3/models/backbones/imagenet_training/train_imagenet.py", line 200, in main
callbacks=[logging, checkpoint, lr_scheduler, terminate_on_nan])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 711, in fit
use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py", line 681, in fit
steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 203, in model_iteration
val_iterator = _get_iterator(val_inputs, model._distribution_strategy)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 546, in _get_iterator
inputs, distribution_strategy)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/distribute/distributed_training_utils.py", line 545, in get_iterator
iterator = distribution_strategy.make_dataset_iterator(dataset)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 978, in make_dataset_iterator
return self._extended._make_dataset_iterator(dataset) # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/mirrored_strategy.py", line 522, in _make_dataset_iterator
split_batch_by=self._num_replicas_in_sync)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/input_lib.py", line 757, in __init__
input_context=input_context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/input_lib.py", line 553, in __init__
input_context=input_context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/input_lib.py", line 511, in __init__
cloned_dataset = input_ops._clone_dataset(dataset) # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/input_ops.py", line 57, in _clone_dataset
remap_dict = _clone_helper(dataset._variant_tensor.op, variant_tensor_ops)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/input_ops.py", line 97, in _clone_helper
op_def=_get_op_def(op_to_clone))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3261, in create_op
attrs, op_def, compute_device)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3330, in _create_op_internal
op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1657, in __init__
self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

I don't know what caused the error. I haven't found the relevant solution on the network. I hope someone can help me solve it, very thanks!

Comment: After a first glance at your code, I noticed the output_shapes parameter of your call to     test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(make_test_generator, output_types=tf.float32, output_shapes=tf.TensorShape([224,224]))
 should have three dimensions (i.e., [224,224,3]) instead of [224,224]

Comment: I tried your plan, but it still made a mistake. The error code is pasted below

Comment: You should really check your data generation process and make sure you're creating your data correctly. Now, I see that your preprocess function returns **x** or **input** only and not any **targets**. Your new error is because you are training a classifier and not giving it any labels to learn from.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the mistake，I change it like this:train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(make_train_generator,output_types=(tf.float32,tf.uint8), output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape((1024, 224, 224, 3)), tf.TensorShape((1024, 1000)))).

Answer (score -1):

I tried @Bashir Kazimi  plan：

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(make_train_generator, output_types=tf.float32, output_shapes=tf.TensorShape([224,224,3]))
```

then, another mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "yolo3/models/backbones/imagenet_training/train_imagenet.py", line 242, in
main(args)
File "yolo3/models/backbones/imagenet_training/train_imagenet.py", line 200, in main
callbacks=[logging, checkpoint, lr_scheduler, terminate_on_nan])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 711, in fit
use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py", line 681, in fit
steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 296, in model_iteration
batch_outs = f(actual_inputs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 3343, in __call__
run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1459, in __call__
run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
(0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'softmax_target_1' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
[[{{node softmax_target_1}}]]
[[metrics_2/top_k_categorical_accuracy/div_no_nan/ReadVariableOp/_4759]]
(1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'softmax_target_1' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
[[{{node softmax_target_1}}]]
0 successful operations.
1 derived errors ignored.
```